# colordialog size

Tags: vb.net, winforms

1. is it possible to adjust the size of the colordialog prompt?
2. is it possible to adjust the size of the sample color boxes within the colordialog prompt?

these are both for vb.net in winforms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, those ColorDialogs are generated by Windows through the .NET Framework. If you do not like it, here is some code for an improved one.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164113.aspx